# Convert tuple to a string

Tags: python, string, tuples

I know tuple to string questions were asked before but i dont really get it the way they explain it so I try to get an explanation on my example.
So i need to convert the tuple points to a string to fill it in in the last line after 'got data'.
This is the script:

```
def on_pick(self, event):

    print('On Pick!')

    thisline = event.artist
    xdata = thisline.get_xdata()
    ydata = thisline.get_ydata()
    ind = event.ind
    print(ind)

    points = tuple(zip(xdata[ind], ydata[ind]))
    print('onpick points:', points)

    QtGui.QMessageBox.information(self, "Click!", 'got data' + points)
```

the call is

```
self.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', self.on_pick)
```

and the output shoul be this as i already described it:

```
QtGui.QMessageBox.information(self, "Click!", 'got data' + points)
```

So where points is written in the last line i want to fill in the string of the tuple points.
Im new to python so dont hate me :D

Comment: Can you add the function call and the output?

Comment: I added it sir but i dont know if the output is ok for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the every element data in the tuple is `string` type, than you can simply do:

```
" ".join(points)
```

where your code should something look like this:

```
QtGui.QMessageBox.information(self, "Click!", 'got data' + " "join(points))
```

where as if there are `int` or `float` types than maybe map `str` or just print them one by one.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
myString = "got data %s, %s" % (str(xdata),str(ydata))
QtGui.QMessageBox.information(self, "Click!", myString)
```

or if xdata is a tuple

```
myString = "got data %s, %s" % (str(xdata[0]),str(xdata[1]))

a = (1,2)
b = "asdf %s %s" % (str(a[0]),str(a[1]))
```